# Linux Ubuntu 16.04 / apt-get issue

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm having issues installing anything on my ubuntu 16.04 since I've messed with java install. Here's what I get --

```
sudo apt-get -f install htop

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done E: The package jre1.8.0-111 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install jre on your system? Also, don't use -f to install software.

Comment: Please don't crosspost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447084/linux-ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-not-working Remove the question from SO, it is off topic there, that site is only for programming.

Comment: I'll remove it from SO

Comment: I've tried to install jre on the system, had some issues, tried a couple of different things from the www and failed. It was a week ago, so I can't remember exactly what I did, but I know it didn't work. Now I can't install anything anymore :(.

Comment: Removing is one thing, but this is preventing me from installing new ones... I'll read through it and let you know.

Comment: @IanisS I think after you remove jre like by the link, it would fix the problem with installing either.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should remove Java. Then reinstall it
You can also try with Synaptic (if you have already installed it)

```
sudo synaptic
```

Or just

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge *java*
```

And then reinstall java

Comment: I've tried all commands here, but all result in the same : 
E: The package jre1.8.0-111 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
Synaptic's not installed, but I can't install anything anyway.

Comment: Try to download jre1.8.0-111 from the Java website and try the command `sudo dpkg --remove jre1.8.0-111`